# Problemas ao implementar um método que envia email

Tags: java, apache

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import org.apache.commons.mail.Email;
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author OctavioCesar
 */
public class SendEmailJava {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        sendemail();
    }

 public static void sendemail() {
        SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();

        email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
        email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
        email.setSmtpPort(465);
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("exemplo_conta@gmail.com", "exemplo_senha"));

        try {
            email.setFrom("exemplo_conta@gmail.com");

            email.setDebug(true);

            email.setSubject("Assunto do E-mail");
            email.setMsg("Texto sem formatação");
            email.addTo("exemplo_receptor@seudominio.com");

            email.send();

        } catch (EmailException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Estou tendo problemas para por isso a funcionar da o seguinte erro na consola

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/D:/Projectos%20JOB%20UEM/JavaMail/javamail1_4_7/javamail-1.4.7/lib/gimap.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/D:/Projectos%20JOB%20UEM/JavaMail/javamail1_4_7/javamail-1.4.7/lib/gimap.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/D:/Projectos%20JOB%20UEM/JavaMail/javamail1_4_7/javamail-1.4.7/lib/imap.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/D:/Projectos%20JOB%20UEM/JavaMail/javamail1_4_7/javamail-1.4.7/lib/imap.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/D:/Projectos%20JOB%20UEM/JavaMail/javamail1_4_7/javamail-1.4.7/lib/pop3.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/D:/Projectos%20JOB%20UEM/JavaMail/javamail1_4_7/javamail-1.4.7/lib/pop3.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/D:/Projectos%20JOB%20UEM/JavaMail/javamail1_4_7/javamail-1.4.7/lib/smtp.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/D:/Projectos%20JOB%20UEM/JavaMail/javamail1_4_7/javamail-1.4.7/lib/smtp.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,gimaps,com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,gimap,com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], gimap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,gimap,com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], gimaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,gimaps,com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailSSLStore,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/D:/Projectos%20JOB%20UEM/JavaMail/javamail1_4_7/javamail-1.4.7/lib/smtp.jar!/META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/D:/Projectos%20JOB%20UEM/JavaMail/javamail1_4_7/javamail-1.4.7/lib/smtp.jar!/META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1421)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1448)
    at SendEmailJava.sendemail(SendEmailJava.java:54)
    at SendEmailJava.main(SendEmailJava.java:32)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1411)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:549)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:354)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:211)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Octavio, provavelmente a sua pergunta está sendo negativada por conta do Stacktrace em uma imagem. Tente copiar e colocar o Stacktrace.

Comment: Octavio seja bem vindo ao sopt. Primeiramente é importante você elaborar uma pergunta que contenha um título objetivo e algumas informações necessárias para que possa obter ajuda mais facilmente. Procure sempre adicionar informações no corpo da pergunta relativas ao problema. Uma dica é sempre adicionar o código e responder as seguintes questões: 1) o que eu já fiz?; 2) O que estou tentando fazer?; 3) Que problemas estou enfrentando?. Com esse básico respondido, sua pergunta já tem uma base para obter respostas :)

Answer (score 1):

Você está pedindo para o cliente de email usar SSL:

```
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
```

Isso requer que a sua aplicação confie e valide o certificado público utilizado pelo servidor smtp.

Você pode encontrar um guia de como fazer o download do certificado público e importar com o keytool [nesse artigo (em Inglês)](http://notepad2.blogspot.ie/2012/04/import-gmail-certificate-into-java.html)

Obtendo o certificado (no Linux com OpenSSL):

```
openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
```

Importando o certificado na keystore padrão (Linux):

```
sudo keytool -import -alias smtp.gmail.com -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file gmail.cert
```